# How to make cell have automatic sequential numbering based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have this column in my document that gets updated every time the command button is hit to submit a new RCA.

[image]

This is the form entry for submitting a new RCA

[image]

How do i get the RCA number to autopopulate with the sequential number based on the first list. So every time it opens it automatically choses the next number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
Public Function GetNextRCANumber(Ref As Range) As String
  Dim s As String, i As Integer, y As Integer, n As Integer
  With Ref
    s = .Worksheet.Cells(.Columns(1).Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)
  End With
  i = Len(s)
  y = CInt(Mid$(s, i - 6, 2))
  If Year(Now()) > y + 2000 Then
    GetNextRCANumber = Format$(Now(), "yy") & "-0001"
  Else
    n = CInt(Mid$(s, i - 3)) + 1
    GetNextRCANumber = y & Format$(n, "-0000")
  End If
End Function
```

Input: Ref - the column of the "RCA Number" list.

Output: string like "23-0006".

The function finds the last non-empty cell in the "RCA Number" list column and increments the number within the current year or starts from 1 over the new year.

The function can be used as the worksheet function as well as VBA function (e. g. "RCA Number" is in "Sheet1!A:A"):

```
Worksheet: GetNextRCANumber(Sheet1!A:A)
VBA: GetNextRCANumber([Sheet1!A:A])
```

You can put `="PHX - RCA " & GetNextRCANumber(Sheet1!A:A)` to right from the 'RCA Number:' cell and this cell will always display the next RCA Number while the 'RCA Number' list is advancing.

Comment: How is it going?